# I want to read a CSV files column using gridFs in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, memory

I have a CSV file in below format which I have stored in gridFS MongoDB.

```
id,mobile
101,8878878787
102,8788998989
```

Now I am reading this file using:

```
GridFSDBFile out = gridfs.findOne(new BasicDBObject( "_id" ,
                        new ObjectId("1b3b4bdbfkgo5i0058869")));
```

when I am writing this out using `out.writeTo( outputFile)`, it's storing the results correctly on hard disk, but my requirement is to read this "out" object and get all the mobile numbers under "Mobile" header in memory. I do not want to write file to hard disk, instead get all mobile records from gridFS directly.

Comment: And I want free beer for the rest of my life. My effort: I save money to buy a brewery. What have you tried or thought of thus far? Remember, SO is a site to ask peers for help to tackle a problem, not a free coding service ;)

Comment: Lol you will get beer for your rest of life..if you have money.

Comment: I have csv data in memory..and trying get just mobile numbers out of it.If anyone knows the solution to that.